# The difference between these words

Tags: differences

I want to ask you about something. Please help me solving my confusion.

So, I've been feeling confused with the word "fail".
Sometimes, I see that people write "You are failed" and the other times, I see that people write "You failed". What's the difference?

And when I opened Google for an answer, instead of getting the answer, I was faced with another confusing word.
It's "finish".
What's the difference between "I'm finished" and "I'm finished" (or even "I've finished")?
I think they all have the same meaning.

If they are the same in meaning, why do they come with different forms?

Please help, kinda find it confusing :(

Comment: "Are failed", while perhaps technically OK, is not idiomatic in most contexts.

Comment: Hi @Agnes, welcome to ELU. Just a note about your question: In the third paragraph where you've written *what's the difference between **I'm finished** and **I'm finished***, you probably meant the difference between **finished** and **failed** (at least that would be my guess based on the rest of your question).  Correcting that misstatement should increase the likelihood of receiving a worthwhile answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a native speaker:

**You failed** means you did not succeed in a task or a test.

**You are failed** means the judge or teacher marked your task or test with a failing grade.

**I'm finished** means I completed my task, as in "No more cake, thank you, I'm finished."

**I'm finished** can also mean I am completely overcome, I am entirely ruined, my long-term opportunities are over, as in "Grandma, I'm finished.  You have led me to ruin my diet completely!" You could also say "No more poker. You finished me!"